# Spring data hibernate upsert transaction error @TransactionalEventListener and @Transactinal

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

I have error with transaction handling in spring data.

Spring boot version with correlating spring data - 2.3.7.
Java - 11

I have a method in my service class(annotated as a Service)

```
    @Transactional
    public void incrementSomething(SomeData data) {
        myRepository.someIncrement(data);
    }
```

My repository(I wanted to have upsert operation):

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SomeData, Long> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO my_table (.....) VALUES (.....) " +
            "ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT some_contraint DO UPDATE " +
            "set something = my_table.something + 1", nativeQuery = true)
    public void someIncrement(@Param("someparam") String data);
```

However I have a strange exception occurring(I have enabled TRACE transaction in springframework).

```
Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.someIncrement] after exception: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

I have no idea why is it happening, because I can see the logs that transaction started, and then completing transaction is happening with error. I have tried to look for similar errors on StackOverflow or similar pages, however none of them works.

Do You know why does this error occur? And how to fix it?

PS:
My Transactional method is from:
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:403)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:531)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:154)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy222.incrementCounter(Unknown Source)
    ...
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    ...
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:305)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.transaction.event.ApplicationListenerMethodTransactionalAdapter$TransactionSynchronizationEventAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodTransactionalAdapter.java:129)
    at org.springframework.transaction.event.ApplicationListenerMethodTransactionalAdapter$TransactionSynchronizationEventAdapter.afterCompletion(ApplicationListenerMethodTransactionalAdapter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:171)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.invokeAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:989)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:964)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:785)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:633)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:386)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    ...
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    ...
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:413)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1668)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:238)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

UPDATE 1:
I have added tests with test containers and the same postgres version. I have verified that running the class which invokes this method works just as expected. The problem starts with the class before -> which sends an event and the event handler(annotated as @TransactionalEventListener) receives it after the commit and then the same path is being invoked and exception occurs.

So currently for me it looks like @TransactionalEventListener doesn't work well with @Transactional.

UPDATE 2:

It works only when @Transaction(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW) is set up(as stated in the comments. However I would like to understand why is that. Normal @Transaction works the same as @Transaction(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW) when no transaction is running and it is directly this case. I am still unable to tell why we need propagation requires new and no simple transactional.

Comment: Can you attach the stack trace

Comment: I have attached the stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a new transaction (`@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)` when invoking such services from within a transaction listener.

Comment: Yes, I have checked that after @ TransactionalEventListener normal @ Transactional doesnt work, but we need @ Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW). But why is that? normal @ Transactional works the same as with propagation requires new if no transaction is running. And after receiving an event there is no transaction running

Comment: You will have to ask the implementer of the transaction manager (not sure what you use). I think the problem is that your thread within which the listener runs is still associated with the transaction, so running another transactional method would participate in that transaction, even though it is already finished.

Comment: But according to the spring docs event is sent only when the transaction is committed. Even when transaction is committed does it mean that the thread is still associated with the transaction?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is, otherwise it would lose the transaction context, but like I said, you have to ask the implementer of the transaction manager.